# from string to datatime in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-conversion

I have a dataset including all days in 2020 where solar and wind generation is measured on a 15 basis:

01.01.2020 00:00 - 01.01.2020 00:15

How do I convert this to datatime?

[image: header and first row]

I already tried this:

```
dftotalload2020['Time (CET/CEST)'] = pd.to_datetime(dftotalload2020['Time (CET/CEST)'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M - %d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

but I get an error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9dLo.png)

Comment: What is the error?  Please update the question.

Comment: Also please provide a reproducible input, images are not accepted

Comment: this is the error: redefinition of group name 'd' as group 6; was group 1 at position 142

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide several times the same fields to [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), rather [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) only one of the two date and convert to datetime:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MTU (CET/CEST)'].str.extract('(.*) -',
                                                             expand=False))
```

Output:

```
                        MTU (CET/CEST)       date
0  01.01.2020 00:00 - 01.01.2020 00:15 2020-01-01
```

Or [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and convert both:

```
df[['date1', 'date2']] = (df['MTU (CET/CEST)'].str.split(r'\s*-\s*', expand=True)
                          .apply(pd.to_datetime)
                         )
```

Output:

```
                        MTU (CET/CEST)      date1               date2
0  01.01.2020 00:00 - 01.01.2020 00:15 2020-01-01 2020-01-01 00:15:00
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Do I have to use the data or the time and not both? If that's what you mean. How can I create a new column for the date and a new column for the time both converted to datetime? Thanks!

Comment: What I mean is that `to_datetime` cannot understand two times the same format field (e.g. %Y), so you have to chose. Can you please provide a reproducible input of your example?

Comment: I provided an example of the outputs for clarity

Comment: You might also want to explore using a `Period` with `df['period'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['MTU (CET/CEST)'].str.extract('(.*) -', expand=False)), freq='15min')`

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! However, due to this split I am not sure how to plot the data. Can you also help me with that? I want the total load on the Y axis and the mean per day on the X axis..

Comment: I'm not sure which method you use to plot, but pass the correct columns as x and y. Please provide your current code if you need help.